# HttpWebRequest just hanging on one computer

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I've got a piece of code the goes out and does an `HttpWebRequest` to Google Wallet. The code works just fine on all my machines, except for this one computer at work that I'm on right now. The Internet on this computer works just fine (as I'm using it right now to type this question) and we have no proxy server at work.

The problem is that it just hangs. It doesn't even timeout. It just hangs with no error message or anything and I have to force close it. Here is the code:

```
    private static string GetLoginHtml()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LoginUrl);
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            string content = "Email=" + Username + "&Passwd=" + Password;
            requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content).Length);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string galxValue = ParseOutValue(html, "GALX");

                return GetLoginHtml2(galxValue, cookieJar);
            }
        }
    }
```

Stepping through the code on the Visual Studio debugger, I know that it hangs when it hits the following line:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
```

Specifically, the `request.GetResponse()` part is what's hanging. Running Fiddler, all I see is a gray entry that looks like this:

```
 3     200    HTTP            Tunnel to     accounts.google.com:443            0
```

There is nothing else. No response body. Do anyone have any suggestions on what could be going on? The fact that its happening on just this one computer tells me that it may not be a programming issue.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Yes. As stated in my question, I step through the code with the Visual Studio Debugger. It hangs on the line `using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I looked _through_ that line of your question. As a diagnostic, I suggest you break that into `using (var rsp = request.GetResponse()) using (var strm = rsp.GetResponseStream()) using (var sr = new StreamReader(strm))`, each on a separate line. It would be interesting to know which of those is hanging.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - lol as stated in my question, its the `request.GetResponse()` part that is hanging.

Comment: And how did you determine that it was not GetResponseStream()?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Because I had broken it up and separated everything onto its own line. When the debugger hit the line `request.GetResponse()`, that's when it hung.

Comment: Sounds like Windows Firewall

Comment: @gordy - Its not a firewall issue. I disabled it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue with this. I'm posting this answer in hopes it might help someone else with some inevitable head scratching in the future.

Here is my working code now:

```
private static string GetLoginHtml()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LoginUrl);
    var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        string content = "Email=" + Username + "&Passwd=" + Password;
        requestStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content).Length);
    }
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string galxValue = ParseOutValue(html, "GALX");

        return GetLoginHtml2(galxValue, cookieJar);
    }
}
```

My guess is that my requestStream wasn't being garbage collected and closed before getting the response stream. I think the response stream was being open and read before the request stream finished writing its bytes. Silly .NET garbage collector

Comment: Your guess is correct.  The stream needed to be flushed, because without either closing it or manually flushing it otherwise, you're not guaranteed when (or if) it's going to happen at all, thus (in this case) meaning your HTTP request will never actually be finished, as far as the server is concerned.  Adding the using block forces the stream to flush and allows the CRLFCRLF sequence which ends an HTTP request to be sent to the server when you call GetResponse().